# Remove manage content and structure for a sharepoint 2010 group

Tags: 2010, permissions

I have a group that needs to be able to submit forms, and add data. However they need to not be able to see the "`manage content and structure`" link under **"site actions"**. I have found a couple solutions, which are for 2007.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointadmin/thread/204665ac-1949-49e4-84ff-d54ce91c2914

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/5222b014-aa67-4622-af95-d0f37efe4684/

To be clear, I only want that one group to be affected.

Any ideas on how to disable/hide "`manage content and structure`" for a specific group would help me immensely.

Answer (score 1):

Originally hiding menu actions or other links can be achieved either by changing permissions - which relies on security triming, or using a custom actions (as already pointed out in the links). Programatically otherwise using Security Triming web control (most likely in  the master page), but in the case of the link you mentioned it cannot be applied as the Item is added dynamically by the Publishing features.

One alternative is to simply use:

1. Create a custom action to call a Javascript function (function
   defined next steps)
2. Create a javascript file where you put a function that Checks if the current user is in the specific Group you are targeting (each group gets a Integer identifier)
3. Create a function which hides the menu item if the above evaluation is True.

For the 1st point see here http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2010/03/01/scriptsrc-referencing-javascript-files-with-sharepoint-2010-custom-actions.aspx

For the 2nd point see here http://spdailytips.blogspot.ch/2011/09/get-current-users-group.html

For the 3rd point http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/395fa726-94c9-4bff-9a63-4613307445aa/ has some code example to put it together for the whole Site Actions menu.